# Spring JSP Checkboxes on List Object

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to use the `<checkboxes>` tag on a List Object. But despite reading the mykong tutorial and searching elsewhere, i can't figure out how that is done.

So here is what i want to do:
I have a class like

```
 class Person{

    List<IceCreams> creams;

    }
```

So now i want to give my User a form where he can choose which IceCreams he likes.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class IceCreamController{

@RequestMapping(value="icecream", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPage(Model model){
Person person = repository.getPerson(); //Returns a Person, "creams" is not empty
model.addAttribute("creams", person.getIceCreams();
}

@RequestMapping(value="icecream", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String showPage( @ModelAttribute("teilnehmer") List<IceCreams> likedCreams, Model model){
//do something with selected iceCreams
}
```

Now i don't understand how to continue in the JSP. I know i have to use the checkboxes tag, but i do not know what it returns on submit or if i use it correctly.

```
<form:form>
<form:checkboxes path="creams" items="${creams}"/>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

So the question is: What do I write in the JSP and what will be returned to the controller?

Added after comment:
IceCream class:

```
  public class IceCream{
   private long id;
   private String creamName;
```

//+getters/setters
    }

---

EDIT: After a helpful answer i tried this:
Adding those to the model:

```
model.addAttribute("person", person);
     model.addAttribute("creams", person.getCreams());
```

and in the JSP i did

```
<form:checkboxes  path="teilnehmer"
                      items="${creams}"
                      itemValue="id"
                      itemLabel="creamName"
                      />
```

So in the POST-Method i take a ModelAttribute Person.

added to Controller:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
   binder.registerCustomEditor(IceCream.class, new IceCreamsPropertyEditor());
```

and the new Editor class:

```
public class ContactsPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

    @Autowired
    IceCreamRepository creamrep;

   @Override
   public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {

         Integer creamId = new Integer(text);
         IceCream cream = creamrep.findOne(creamId);
         super.setValue(con);

   }
}
```

Sadly the result is Error 400.

Comment: can you post your `IceCreams` class

Comment: Can you post the updated controller.

Comment: Please also fix typos in your code e.g. contacts contactId and superSetvalue(con) do not make sense.

Comment: Changed it, sorry. The new controller is really just the old one, just added the person object to the model.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot bind to a raw list. You need to bind to the object wrapping the list: in your case that is an instance of Person rather than the List creams.

So, put the Person in the model. Use a `@ModelAttribute` method so the framework will reload the same person on submit and set the values. Most likely we would want to present all available ice creams for selection.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadForEdit(){
    return "";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person){
    repository.savePerson(person);  

    return "";
}

//called by the framework on 'get' to load the person you wish to edit
//called by the framework on on 'post' to get the same instance for binding
//send personId as a hidden form element in the form
@ModelAttribute("person")
public Person getPerson(@RequestParam int personId){
    return repository.getPerson(personId);  
} 

@ModelAttribute("iceCreams")
public List<String> getAvailableIceCreams(){
    return repository.findAll();    
}
```

Secondly, the framework cannot automatically convert from the submitted form parameters to instances of IceCream. To do that you will need to look at using a converter but that is another question. See here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Given the above then we can get a simpler example working for now by changing  the collection type to String:

```
class Person{
    List<String> creams;
}
```

The JSP should then simply become:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="person">
    <!-- bind to the creams property of person -->
    <!-- create check boxes for all available ice creams -->
    <!-- any already in person.creams should be automatically checked -->
    <form:checkboxes path="creams" items="${iceCreams}" />
    <input type="hidden" value="${person.id}" name="personId"/>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

Once you are familiar with converters you can convert to bind to IceCream instances but that is too broad a topic. However in your JSP you should simply need to update the checkboxes tag as below:

```
<form:checkboxes path="creams" items="${iceCreams}"  itemValue="id" itemLabel="labelName"/>
```

where value is the property that will be submitted to the server and which will be used by your converter to create the correct instance (e.g. the ID of an items saved in a database) and label is the property to be used for display.

Comment: I want to learn it right, so i tried the "complicated" approach. Updated it in the question